# Managing global objects in Django

Tags: django, session

**Context:**
I was going through various guides, tutorials and also posts here in the stackoverflow.
I need to handle process, e.g., - “pick topic —> show author list —> delete all —> ask confirmation —> show result —> go back to author list”

The obvious (and simplistic) approach is to create sets of views for each process.
And save process state in session variables or pass via URL-s (however, I discovered this method can be very brittle if too many information is passed). Also I need to tell each view where to go next, and this mushrooms into a bulky chain of instructions repeated for each URL request.

Instead, I want two extra things:

1. encapsulate a process at single place
2. re-use views, e.g. to re-use Topic List view to pick a single topic. That is, to work in “picker mode”.  (btw, if I try to do this with multiple view classes, the next view class needs to know what to do and where to return…)

I also checked django workflow libs, and so on. and still not convinced.

**Question:**

if I create global object to encapsulate process and reference it from the current session - is this a good idea? My main concern is that - as sessions come  and go, who will be cleaning up this global object?

is it possible to somehow make this clean up automatic? that is, when session goes away, some method is called where I can clean up or help GC to collect unneeded object? Like C++ destructors?

Answer (score 0):

after working further with code, it occured to me that if I add global object to the session (and nowhere else) - it must be garbage collected in due course, because session itself is managed by Django.....

also, reading https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/class-based-views/intro/ in my 3rd pass, found that Django's as_view() instatiates a new instance of class based views on each HTTP request.
so, everything is per request basis, and data will be transient. So only way to maintain state across HTTP requests is to either persist in the database or use sessions (or keep passing "state" from each request to request via URL parameters, but it is bulky, unsafe. my understanding is that this is a fallback mechanism if cookies are not allowed and session can be simulated via this way, e.g. PHP does it).